# Connecting form to SQL Database

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I am able to connect to mysql database however I can not display data from my form to my database. I am not sure why this is happening but I have been able to retrieve data from my database I just can not enter information into it. For now I am just trying to enter First_Name. I also get no errors when entering in data to the form. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

```
   <p>
  <form name="input1" action="http://seanfagan.webuda.com/Final/club.php" method="post">
   First_Name:<input type="text" name="First_Name"><br>
   Last_Name: <input type="text" name="Last_Name"><br>
   Club_Name: <input type="text" name="Club_Name"><br>
   Email:     <input type="text" name="Email"><br>
   Club_Type: <input type="text" name="Club_Type"><br>
   Members: <input type="text" name="Members"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Send"><br>
   </form>
   <?php
   $mysql_host = "mysql14.000webhost.com";
   $mysql_database = "a9576602_Final";
   $mysql_user = "a9576602_Final";
   $mysql_password = "*****![enter image description here][1]";
   $mysql_error = "Could not connect to database!";

   $conn = mysql_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_password) or die ("$mysql_error");
   $select_db= mysql_select_db('a9576602_Final') or die ("Couldn't select database!");

   $value = $_Post['input1'];
   $sql = "INSERT INTO Club (First_Name) VALUES ('First_Name')";

   if (!mysql_query($sql)) {
      die('Errorss: ' . mysql_error());
       }


  mysql_close();

 ?>
 </p>
```

Comment: `$_Post` should be `$_POST`. Is that a copying error or in the real code?

Comment: Should also check if the request is a POST request before attempting to use `$_POST` values. When it is a POST request, `$_POST` will be populated with the form field names, not the form name

Comment: Also, the *mysql* extension (`mysql_*` functions) has been deprecated. You should be using *mysqli* or PDO.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your connection with the database is okay. You can put a `<name>` attribute for your submit button to serve as a reference for sending your form via $_POST method:

```
<input type = "submit" name = "input1" value = "Submit">
```

Then using this, you can trigger your insert statement:

> ```
> <?php
>      if(isset($_POST['input1']))
>        {
>           // make sure you also declare the variables in your form such as the first name, etc.
>           $firstName = $_POST['First_Name'];
>           mysql_query("INSERT INTO Club (First_Name) VALUES ('$firstName')");
>        }
> ?>
> ```

Hope this helps you :D